# Linux SMP system: User process, Kernel module functions, Kernel module interrupt handler, SLUBs: run on which core?

Tags: linux, cache, kernel-module, scheduling

I'm having some uncertainties regarding the kernelspace / userspace  behaviour of multicore multithread systems, especially in combination with allocations using SLUB.
Could you please give me some feedback regarding my perceptions?

On SMP system the task/process scheduler decides which task will be ran on which core, for user- and kernel- processes/tasks. (check) But what happens if:

1. A user process is executed on Core 2 and the code makes a call to a kernel module (say by using IOCTL), will the kernel code also run on Core 2 within the same 'time slice'.? (I would say yes)
2. Say, we're in case 1 (we're running the IOCTL kernel module code) and there's an IRQ fired for a handler inside the same kernel module that's executing the IOCTL function. Is it possible that that IRQ_handler will run on the other core? (I would say yes as it's handled through the scheduler)
3. Does the answer for case 2 (IRQ_Handler on other core) also apply for Kernel threads? (I would say yes as it's handled through the scheduler)
4. In case 2: Is it wise to have objects (intermediate driver/module storage) allocated in SLUBs, when using as a shared data-register between intensive called IRQ_handlers, kernel threads (worker) and the IOCTL code? As I read that SLUBs are loaded into L1 cache and become per-cpu copies? There's little info to find on the SLUB (or I'm not using optimal search expressions).
5. Better options for question 4 ( SLAB, SLOB, static/global declaration, ...?)

Best regards,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't agree, the context is required.